# Using JEditorPane instead of default JLabel in JTable

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jtable, jeditorpane

Trying to use JEditorPane for one column in a JTable without any success. Main reason for this is that I want to add a hyperLinkListener and JEditorPane should apparently be a better choice for this than the default JLabel.

```
private void createQueueTable (String[] columnNames){
Object[][] rows 

    queueModel      = new DefaultTableModel(rows,columnNames){
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                ...
                case 9:
                    return String.class;    //Comment
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }
    };

    queueTable.setModel(queueModel)    
    TableColumnModel queueTableColumnModel  = queueTable.getColumnModel();      
    TableCellRenderer tcr = new CustomTableCellRenderer();  
    TableCellRenderer scr = new        CustomTablePaneCellRenderer();                       

    int counter =0
    while(counter<columnNames.size()-1){
        queueTableColumnModel.getColumn(counter).setCellRenderer(tcr);
        counter++
    }

    queueTableColumnModel.getColumn(counter).setCellRenderer(scr);      
    ...     
}    
    public class CustomTablePaneCellRenderer extends JTextPane implements TableCellRenderer {
        public CustomTablePaneCellRenderer() {
            setContentType("text/html");
        }

         public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);    
                if (isSelected) {
                 } 
                 else{
                      if (row % 2 == 0) 
                            cell.setBackground(new Color(248,248,248))
                      else
                          cell.setBackground(Color.white)
                 } 
                 return cell;
        }           
    }
```

---

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: CustomTablePaneCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent() is applicable for argument types: (EMSMonster$1, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [EMSMonster$1[,0,0,1280x304,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=251658568,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,autoCreateColumnsFromModel=true,autoResizeMode=AUTO_RESIZE_OFF,cell
SelectionEnabled=true,editingColumn=-1,editingRow=-1,gridColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=122,g=138,b=153],preferredViewportSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=450,height=400],rowHeight=16,rowMargin=1,rowSelectionAllowed=true,selectionBackground=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],selectionForeground=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],showHorizontalLines=true,showVerticalLines=true], ...]
Possible solutions: getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable, java.lang.Object, boolean, boolean, int, int)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at CustomTablePaneCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(EMSMonster.groovy:2613)
        at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5731)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
        at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
        at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

This is how it should look like more or less. 
[image: Screenshot]

Reading several other posts I am starting to doubt if it is at all possible to have text AND clickable links in the same table cell.

Many thanks for any further help!!

Answer (score 2):

> Main reason for this is that I want to add a
>   hyperLinkListener and JEditorPane should apparently be a better choice
>   for this than the default JLabel.

I would actually argue against that.  The main reason being, a cell renderer is just a "snapshot" of the component it is renderer, it is not a active component.  This means it does not respond to user input, such as key or mouse listeners, for example.

Personally, I would simple "render" a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to look like a standard hyperlink.

I would then establish a "special" editor that would respond only to mouse clicks and would activate the hyper link accordingly...

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class TableHyperLink {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableHyperLink();
    }

    public TableHyperLink() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    MyModel model = new MyModel();
                    JTable table = new JTable(model);
                    table.setDefaultRenderer(URL.class, new URLTableCellRenderer());
                    table.setDefaultEditor(URL.class, new URLTableCellEditor());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public MyModel() throws MalformedURLException {
            super(new Object[][]{{new URL("http://stackoverflow.com")}}, 
                    new Object[]{"Link"});
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return URL.class; // Only have one column :P
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public class URLTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public URLTableCellRenderer() {
            setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            if (value instanceof URL) {
                value = "<html><u>" + ((URL)value).toString() + "</u></html>";
                setText(value.toString());
            }
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            return this;
        }

    }

    public class URLTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private URL url;

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return url;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            JLabel editor = new JLabel("Clicked");
            if (value instanceof URL) {
                url = (URL) value;
                editor.setText("<html><ul>" + url.toString() + "</ul></html>");
            }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopCellEditing();
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
                    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
            boolean editable = false;
            if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) e;
                if (me.getClickCount() == 1 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me)) {
                    editable = true;
                }
            }
            return editable;
        }
    }        
}
```

Your other choice would be to attach a `MouseListener` to the table and monitor the mouse clicks.  This would involve you having to convert the mouse point to a column index and determining if the column is the correct column in the model, looking up the value in the model and then processing it as required.

It's more messy, less portable and error prone - IMHO

**Additional example based on feedback**

I just want to point out that this is hack.  The URL extraction is based on the answer from [Handling hyperlink right clicks on a JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932089/handling-hyperlink-right-clicks-on-a-jtextpane)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;

public class TableHyperLink {

    public static final String PASSWORD_PROMPT = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableHyperLink();
    }

    public TableHyperLink() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    MyModel model = new MyModel();
                    JTable table = new JTable(model);
                    TableColumn column = table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(0));
                    column.setCellEditor(new URLTableCellEditor());
                    column.setCellRenderer(new URLTableCellRenderer());

                    column = table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(1));
                    column.setCellEditor(new URLTableCellEditor());
                    column.setCellRenderer(new URLTableCellRenderer());

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public MyModel() throws MalformedURLException {
            super(new Object[][]{
                {"<html>This is a <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838196/using-jeditorpane-instead-of-default-jlabel-in-jtable/18838244?noredirect=1#comment27831752_18838244'>Test</a>",
                    "<html>This is a <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838196/using-jeditorpane-instead-of-default-jlabel-in-jtable/18838244?noredirect=1#comment27831752_18838244'>Test</a>"}},
                    new Object[]{"Link", "Link1"});
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class; // Only have one column :P
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    /**
     * JEditorPane based renderer.  This gives me issues with fonts, so
     * you may need to do some more playing around with this to 
     * get it to work the way you want
     */
    public class URLTableCellRenderer extends JEditorPane implements TableCellRenderer {

        public URLTableCellRenderer() {
            // Set the content type
            setContentType("text/html");
            // Get rid of the default border
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
            // Get rid of any margins
            setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText(value == null ? null : value.toString());
            return this;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Drop in editor, this really is just a event factory used to capture the events
     * and process them...
     */
    public class URLTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        // This is the value returned to the table model, because I've used a DefaultTableModel
        // this is very important
        private Object value;
        // The point that the mouse click occured
        private Point clickPoint;
        // The url to open
        private URL url;

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            // Capture the current cell value
            this.value = value;
            // Something to return to the table...
            JLabel editor = new JLabel(value == null ? null : value.toString());

            // Get the cell renderer for the current cell
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            // Get the cell component for the renderer (expecting a JEditorPane)
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            // Set the bounds of the component to meet the requirements for the cell rect
            comp.setBounds(table.getCellRect(row, column, false));
            if (comp instanceof JEditorPane) {
                // Get the JEditorPane
                JEditorPane editPane = (JEditorPane) comp;
                // Asdjust the click point to be within the
                // editor context
                clickPoint.x -= comp.getLocation().x;
                clickPoint.y -= comp.getLocation().y;
                try {
                    // Try and get the hyperlink that was clicked
                    url = getHyperlink(editPane, clickPoint);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Dispose of the editor...
                    // You could use cancelCellEditing() instead and the table won't
                    // try and update the model...
                    stopCellEditing();
                    // Open the URL if possible
                    if (url != null) {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
                        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return editor;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
            boolean editable = false;
            if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
                MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) e;
                if (me.getClickCount() == 1 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me)) {
                    editable = true;
                    // We need to the point that the mouse event occured...
                    clickPoint = me.getPoint();
                }
            }
            return editable;
        }

        /*
         * Try and extract the URL from the hyperlink at the given point
         */
        protected URL getHyperlink(JEditorPane editor, Point p) throws MalformedURLException {
            int pos = editor.viewToModel(p);
            return getHyperlink(editor.getDocument(), pos);
        }

        /*
         * Get the hyperlink from the supplied document at the given position in the document
         */
        protected URL getHyperlink(Document doc, int pos) throws MalformedURLException {
            URL url = null;
            Element h = getHyperlinkElement(doc, pos);
            if (h != null) {
                Object attribute = h.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
                if (attribute instanceof AttributeSet) {
                    AttributeSet set = (AttributeSet) attribute;
                    String href = (String) set.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
                    if (href != null) {
                        url = new URL(href);
                    }
                }
            }
            return url;
        }

        /*
         * Get the element from the document that represents a hyperlink based on the position
         * within teh document.  null if it's not a hyperlink element...
         */
        protected Element getHyperlinkElement(Document doc, int pos) {
            if (pos >= 0 && doc instanceof HTMLDocument) {
                HTMLDocument hdoc = (HTMLDocument) doc;
                Element elem = hdoc.getCharacterElement(pos);
                if (elem.getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A) != null) {
                    return elem;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help MadProgrammer. However, I forgot to mention that the column should also be able to contain plain text and not only a url. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: It comes down to what type the underlying data is. I'd be tempted to wrap it in a common Class type. It would have getText and getURL methods, only one of which would return a non-null value. From there you would be able to determine a course of action...

Comment: The underlying data is only text/html. According **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203734/hyperlinks-in-jeditorpane-in-a-jtable)** the EditorPane isn't receiving any events because the component returned from the TableCellRenderer is only allowed to display, and not intercept events. I am pretty lost how to get it working.

Comment: Is the text likely to contain more than one URL?

Comment: Ideally it should be able to deal with multiple links in one cell. However, it is much more likely there is only text and no url at all than multiple urls. In many cases the cell will probably just be left completely empty. If there are no possibilities to get it working with more than one url, then that would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: There are "ideas", some more messy then others ;)

Comment: Don't know if its really that exceptional idea trying to display text with clickable links in a JTable cell.. anyway, thanks for any further suggestions, I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: I've posted another solution, it's messy and a little hacky

Comment: You've need to set the editor for the column to use the custom editor

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant solution!! Its working great, but when I try to merge it with my code, none of the functions in `URLTableCellEditor` is getting called for some strange reason, despite setting it like this  ` queueTableColumnModel.getColumn(9).setCellEditor(new URLTableCellEditor());
queueTableColumnModel.getColumn(9).setCellRenderer(new URLTableCellRenderer());`

Comment: Found the problem!! When creating the table the 
`isCellEditable(int row,int column)` function was configured to return false in my code. Everything is now working as expected after changing it to return `true` instead. Thanks again for your help MadProgrammer!!!

Comment: It's a little hacky, so be gentle with it ;)